# how to " sort csv file" python

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I'm trying to create a new file that contains only the data for movies with a rank above 9.

The dataset that I'm analyzing contains rating on many movies obtained from IMDB. 
The data fields are:

- `Votes`: the number of people rating the movie
- `Rank`: the averate rating of the movie
- `Title`: the name of the movie
- `Year`: the year in which the movie was released

The code I tried:

```
import csv

filename = "IMDB.txt"
with open(filename, 'rt', encoding='utf-8-sig') as imdb_file:
    imdb_reader = csv.DictReader(imdb_file, delimiter = '\t')
    with open('new file.csv', 'w', newline='') as high_rank:
        fieldnames = ['Votes', 'Rank', 'Title', 'Year']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(high_rank, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for line_number, current_row in enumerate (imdb_reader):
            if(float(current_row['Rank']) > 9.0):
                csv_writer.writerow(dict(current_row))
```

but unfortunately its not working, what should i do ?

Comment: What is not working? Please provide a [MCVE] including example input (if large, link to IMDB file, plus at least a few example lines), expected output, and actual output.

Comment: Some notes: `csv_writer.writerow(dict(current_row))` doesn't need the `dict()` wrapping (`current_row` is already a `dict`). You didn't pass `newline=''` when opening the input file (you should do so consistently); the mode defaults to `'r'` (where the `t` is implied) so you can omit that argument from the first `open` entirely. Also, just for clarity, I'm guessing your input is in Excel's tab separated format; you can opt in to that exact dialect with `dialect='excel-tab'`; passing just `delimiter='\t'` doesn't make it clear you're exactly matching Excel's format.

Comment: Also, just to be clear, I don't see any data files matching your exact format on [IMDB's interfaces site](https://www.imdb.com/interfaces/). Are you sure the column headers *exactly* match what you're expecting?

Comment: the link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/65y4pi9o0kczz98/IMDB.txt?dl=0

Comment: i just want to create a new file that contains only the data for movies with a rank above 9.  the error that i get from my code is : UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u01e1' in position 6: character maps to <undefined>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56365001/how-to-sort-csv-file-python/56366367#comment99335522_56365001), your locale default encoding appears to be something that doesn't support the whole Unicode range. You need to specify an encoding for the output file that will handle arbitrary Unicode characters. Typically, on non-Windows systems you'd use `'utf-8'`; on Windows, you might use `'utf-16'` or `'utf-8-sig'` (Windows programs often assume UTF-8 without an explicit signature is in the locale encoding, and misinterpret it). The fix is as simple as changing:

```
with open('new file.csv', 'w', newline='') as high_rank:
```

to:

```
with open('new file.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as high_rank:
```

changing the specified `encoding` to whatever makes sense for your OS and use case.

Answer (score 0):

Let's considere you have the following excel sheet name `temp.csv` and you want to filter films with a rank above 9 (included):

One simple way to do is to use the `pandas` modules. It gives you the opportunity to :

- **read** `.csv` files with `pd.read_csv` method [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)
- **filter** data as you want
- **export** data to a new file : for `.csv` output, `df.to_csv` do the job [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Assume you have the following dataframe:

[image]

The code bellow do the job:

```py
# import modules
import pandas as pd

# Path - name of your file
filename = "temp.csv"

# Read the csv file
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=";")
print(df)
#    Votes  Rank                               Film  Year
# 0     15    16          The Shawshank Redemption   1994
# 1   2004     5                     The Godfather   1972
# 2    486    13            The Godfather: Part II   1974
# 3    529     9  Il buono, il brutto, il cattivo.   1966
# 4    289    12                      Pulp Fiction   1994
# 5     98    11                         Inception   2010
# 6     69    18                  Schindler's List   1993
# 7      3     7                         Angry Men   1957
# 8    584    14   One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest   1975

# Filter the csv file
df_filtered = df[df["Rank"] >= 9]
print(df_filtered)
#    Votes  Rank                               Film  Year
# 0     15    16          The Shawshank Redemption   1994
# 2    486    13            The Godfather: Part II   1974
# 3    529     9  Il buono, il brutto, il cattivo.   1966
# 4    289    12                      Pulp Fiction   1994
# 5     98    11                         Inception   2010
# 6     69    18                  Schindler's List   1993
# 8    584    14   One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest   1975

# name new csv file
new_filename = filename[:-3] + "_new" + filename[-3:]

# Export dataframe to csv file
df_filtered.to_csv(new_filename)
```

The new `.csv` looks like this:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the help, but the new file only gave me 9 result it should be 18635 results, do you know what is the problem ? this is the file link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/65y4pi9o0kczz98/IMDB.txt?dl=0                                              i get the error :  ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 236, saw 2

Comment: This is a `text` file, you wrote `.csv` on the title.